# Displaying data from sql using paragraphs instead of one line (string)

Tags: php, html, string

I`m new to this topic and I wanted to ask you to help me with this case.

I`m working on the website where you can create your profile and add description. When you display description later on the page, it appears in one line (no paragraphs as it was written in the textarea filed using "enter"). Does anyone know how to breake it into paragraphs?

This is the type of field where it is saved:

```
<textarea name="descripton">{$descripton}</textarea>
```

This is the place on the website where it is published:

```
<div class="profile-description">{$descripton}</div>
```

Which code I should use to publish it not in single line but within paragraphs?

Thank you for your help!

Kris

Comment: If you enter "breaks" into the textarea, you might later replace them (the "breaks", use DOUBLE QUOTES: `"\n"`) with `<br>` or anything else. Do you have any `code` to show as, where `{$description}` is processed?

Answer (score 1):

To allow proper formatting of the user descriptions you should use one of the web based WYSIWYG editors, most popular one is [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `nl2br()` to convert the newlines in the description into HTML `<br>` tags.

```
$description = nl2br($description);
echo "<div class='profile-description'>{$descripton}</div>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Now I have noticed that I have 2 different fields (maybe types of fields) because if I put "enters" while editing description of the profile it appears okey within one field later when it is published and I see in the html code that there is <br>.
But with the second field it doesn`t work. If I put "enters" I cant see <br> in the html later. 

I tried to use:
'$description = nl2br($description);
echo "<div class='profile-description'>{$descripton}</div>";'

it didnt work-maybe I do something wrong

website is here: [link]http://www.einstruktor.pl/profil/spikey/4

Comment: I'm not understanding you. Could you update your question with more details about the problem?

Comment: Old code to publish data from sql base: 
<br/>
<table width="560" height="50" class="profil-dane"> <tr><td valign="top"> <div class="dysp">{$omnie}</div> </td></tr> </table>

Comment: Should it look like this:<br/>
<table width="560" height="50" class="profil-dane">
<tr><td valign="top">
<div class="dysp"><?php
$omnie = nl2br($omnie);
echo "<div>{$omnie}</div>";
?></div>
</td></tr>
</table>

Comment: I asked you to update your question for a reason: code is hard to read in comments. Put it into the question and format it readably with the `{}` code tool.

Comment: Barmar - Thank you for the clue with "nl2br" command. I found a solution in different file. Have a nice day!